# Cannot call System::Action^

Tags: c++-cli

I have a C++/CLI project. In this C++/CLI project I've written a small helper for easing the pains that can convert from a System::Action/Func to a C++ callable. Here's an example of one specialization.

```
template<> struct Callable<void()> {
    Callable(System::Action^ f) : func(std::move(f)) {}
    Handle<System::Action> func;
    void operator()() {
        System::Action^ f = *func;
        f();
    }
};
```

However, this code does not compile. It tells me that `System::Action::Invoke` is inaccessible and cannot be called.

How can I invoke a `System::Action` from C++/CLI?

Comment: `std::move` is useless on tracking pointers -- you're going to make a copy of the pointer regardless.  And `Handle<System::Action>` shouldn't be possible, it needs to be `Handle<System::Action^>`.

Comment: What does your `Handle` class provide that `gcroot` doesn't?

Comment: @BenVoigt: I just got here (in C++/CLI). I was only aware of the untyped GCHandle. I know that you're used to omnipotence and omniscience from me, so try to sit down for a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a case of the compiler simply misreporting the problem, which was actually inside another specialization being instantiated where the argument was a native type that System::Action could not handle. I have no idea why it chose to give me the error in the question instead of the actual error.

Comment: It's karma.  The compiler knows what you named that chatroom.

Answer (score 1):

Use `msclr::gcroot` to hold tracking pointers inside native types.

This code compiles fine for me on VS2013:

```
#include <msclr\gcroot.h>

struct CallableAction
{
    msclr::gcroot<System::Action^> func;
    CallableAction(System::Action^ f) : func(f) {}
    void operator()()
    {
        func->Invoke();
    }
};
```

It should also work fine as a template, I just simplified that so I wouldn't have to worry about whether it was being instantiated properly and fully error checked.